# Kitchenaid oven display malfunctioning

Tags: oven

Older model KEBC277KSS03, dual electric oven with convection at top. The last couple months the display gets very dim, sometimes totally faded out, when oven is on. Did some research and one common cause is fouled contacts on the flexible printed cable (FPC) that connects the control board to the display. So I opened it up and disconnected the FPC from the control board. The FPC looked pristine. However, after plugging this FPC back into the connector on the control board the display is now totally off. When I power the oven on at the breaker, and press 'Bake' and 'Start' I get one short beep, one long beep, and then three short beeps. If I just press 'Start' I get three short beeps. I'm not familiar at all with this type of connection (FPC) and it seems to be in as far as it will go inside the connector. The connector itself has a rectangular, black plastic piece at the top that can be lifted off and pushes down onto the connector after the FPC has been inserted to lock it in place. Also, I disconnected most of the other wired connections from the oven to the control board and pushed them right back in (just to make sure they were in tight and also to rub the contacts a bit in case there was corrosion or fouling).
So there are two issues - the dim display (which doesn't seem to be caused by a fouled FPC connection) and the much bigger problem I caused when trying to reconnect the FPC (no display at all and a totally unusable oven). I have located some replacement control boards online BUT if I can't connect the FPC correctly it's no help.

[image: side view of connection]

[image: front view of connection]

Comment: Are you sure you fully seated the FPC—on both ends?  And that you've fully seated all the other connectors?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot to unpack here, and not that much hard data, so what follows is the way I would approach this based on odds and intuition from my own experience, YMMD:

Given the system stopped working after you disconnected and reconnected the display ribbon cable, it seems likely that the failure was in some way the result of the physical disturbance.

1. The most likely cause would be misalignment when reseating the FPC in the connector.  Release it and inspect the cable and connector for damage (crease, wrinkle, break, etc.) and fix if you can.  If unrepairable, find a replacement.
2. Look for signs of cracked or broken solder joints at all connectors.  A tenuous connection could have broken if it was moved while inspecting the unit.  I have heard reports of old solder joints with high tin content becoming brittle with age. (But I have not ever seen such myself after enough time at this that I too am becoming "brittle with age").
3. The beep pattern is almost certainly an error code.  Have you searched for "KEBC277KSS03 error codes"?  Most of the references will probably be for alphanumeric codes on the display, which of course are useless if it doesn't work.  But somewhere there will be a list of auditory codes.  Have you tried Kitchenaid Tech support?  Some of the third party parts suppliers have troubleshooting guides that might help identify the codes.
4. As for the fading display, I suspect either a failing display unit (which would need replacement) or a failing component in the power supply energizing the display.  If you get the display working again and it still fades, and you're both skilled enough *and know how to do this safely*, you could monitor the voltage to the display and see if it drops as it dims (which would point to the driver board, otherwise, to the display).
5. Does the display fade only when the oven heats up?  There are some reports of that; again, search the service and parts supply sites for this scenario.
   I hope something here will either fix it or yield additional information to point to next steps.  Let us know how it goes, and good luck!

Comment: Yep, these displays do simply dim over time, and the only real solution is a new replacement unit.  The other solution is to just live with it, as long as the dim display can be read.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had better news and really appreciate the replies.

So, I was thinking that maybe there was some gunk inside the FPC connector which was preventing the FPC from seating properly (I actually tried 3 times to get it back in there and as far as I could tell, it was properly seated inside the connector), so I got some contact cleaner.

When I started to pull out the oven again from the wall to test this theory, the lower door got stuck shut on one side (my bad). When I tried to pull the door back open, the lower glass panel basically shattered. Not sure if this is normal or brittle due to age, but it did not take much force for the whole panel to just implode.

In retrospect, it would have been wiser to hold off on fooling with this thing until after Christmas. Given that all I could find as a replacement for the control board was a very pricey rebuilt board, and that the issue was probably (as suggested here) a failing display, it's probably best to just find a replacement (not that I have a choice at this point, anyway).

Again I really do appreciate the help here.

Comment: If the *only* problem was shattered door glass, that is quite fixable - I've done that a few times. But you've also got control panel issues and who knows what else will fail next...